# option select form always deleting the sql query

Tags: wp-query, database

I have this form:

```
<tr class="user-statusz-wrap">
  <th><label for="statusz"><?php _e('Státusz') ?></label></th>
  <td>
    <select type="text" name="statusz" id="statusz">
      <option value disabled selected> -- válassz egyet -- </option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Kezdő', get_the_author_meta( 'statusz', $user->ID ) ); ?>">Kezdő</option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Aktív', get_the_author_meta( 'statusz', $user->ID ) ); ?>">Aktív</option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Pártoló', get_the_author_meta( 'statusz', $user->ID ) ); ?>">Pártoló</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Which is making this SQL query:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'klubadatok_vezetoseg_sql' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'klubadatok_vezetoseg_sql' );
function klubadatok_vezetoseg_sql( $user_id ) {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_users', $user_id ) ) // "edit_users" means it has to be administrator or editor!
    return false;
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'statusz', $_POST['statusz'] );
}
```

And there is this field which is listed for the users in the profile:

```
<tr class="user-statusz-wrap">
  <th><label for="statusz"><?php _e('Státusz') ?></label></th>
  <td><p><?php echo $user->statusz . '<br />';?></p>
  <p class="description"><?php _e('Jelenlegi státuszod a klubban: Kezdő, Aktív, Pártoló.'); ?></p></td>
</tr>
```

My problem is if I leave at first default select option active when I save it, it will re-write the SQL data in the database with the empty. :(

SOLVED!

```
<tr class="user-statusz-wrap">
  <th><label for="statusz"><?php _e('Státusz') ?></label></th>
  <td>
    <select type="text" name="statusz" id="statusz">
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'statusz', $user->ID ) ); ?>"> -- válassz egyet -- </option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Kezdő', get_the_author_meta( 'statusz', $user->ID ) ); ?>">Kezdő</option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Aktív', get_the_author_meta( 'statusz', $user->ID ) ); ?>">Aktív</option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Pártoló', get_the_author_meta( 'statusz', $user->ID ) ); ?>">Pártoló</option>
    </select>
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="statusz" value=" -- válassz egyet -- " disabled />-->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't tag your option as `selected` if you don't want it selected, which means that you should probably be using [`selected()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) to dynamically select any value that has already been set. That should solve the problem.

But this could be cleaned up a lot:

1. `esc_attr()` accepts a single parameter. You are sending it two.
2. It would be easier and cleaner to pull the user meta once and store
   it in a variable.
3. As mentioned, used `selected()`

So...

```
$statusz = get_the_author_meta( 'statusz', $user->ID ); ?>
<tr class="user-statusz-wrap">
  <th><label for="statusz"><?php _e('Státusz') ?></label></th>
  <td>
    <select type="text" name="statusz" id="statusz">
      <option value disabled selected> -- válassz egyet -- </option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr('Kezdő'); ?>" <?php selected( 'Kezdő', $statusz);?> >Kezdő</option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr('Aktív'); ?>" <?php selected( 'Aktív', $statusz);?>>Aktív</option>
      <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'Pártoló'); ?>" <?php selected( 'Pártoló', $statusz);?>>Pártoló</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```